# Type Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider') at fetchingData

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, solana, web3-react

It must show console log Big Number instead its showing error.

- [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/337K3.png)
- [error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L81nV.png)

I have connected the private key of hardhat with wallet but its showing Type Error. The expected output and the output which Ive got has attached along with this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";

//INTERNAL IMPORT
import {
    checkIfWalletConnected,
    connectWallet,
    connectingWithBooToken,
    connectingWithLIfeToken,
    connectingWithSingleSwapToken,
    connectingWithIWTHToken,
    connectingWithDAIToken,
} from "../Utils/appFeatures";

import { IWETHABI } from "./constants";
// import ERC20 from "./ERC20.json";

export const SwapTokenContext = React.createContext();
export const SwapTokenContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const swap = "Welcome to swap my token";

    //USESTATE
  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
  const [ether, setEther] = useState("");
  const [networkConnect, setNetworkConnect] = useState("");
  const [weth9, setWeth9] = useState("");
  const [dai, setDai] = useState("");

  const [tokenData, setTokenData] = useState([]);
  const addToken = [
   "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
   "0x15Ff10fCc8A1a50bFbE07847A22664801eA79E0f",
   "0xAe9Ed85dE2670e3112590a2BB17b7283ddF44d9c",
  ];


  //FETCH DATA
  const fetchingData = async () => {
    try{
      //GET USER ACCOUNT
      const userAccount = await checkIfWalletConnected();
      setAccount(userAccount);
      //CREATE PROVIDER
      const web3modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      //CHECK Balance
      const balance = await provider.getBalance(userAccount);
      console.log(balance);

    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchingData();
  },[]);
  
    return (
        <SwapTokenContext.Provider value={{swap}}>
          {children}
        </SwapTokenContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your imports are probably failed try to import like this instead :

```dart
const ethers = require("ethers");
const BigNumber  = require("ethers");
```